# How to get a value from nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get a value from the nested JSON data below. Specifically, the payments captures id value `0TA12948FV40723B` is the value I need.

I try using the following codes to retrieve the value.

```
details.purchase_units.payments.captures.id

details.purchase_units.payments[0].captures.id
```

But I keep getting a console.log Error: "Order could not be captured"

JSON DATA

```
{
    "create_time":"2019-02-19T05:06:52Z",
    "update_time":"2019-02-19T05:06:52Z",
    "id":"3HB96413YD922272B",
    "intent":"CAPTURE",
    "status":"COMPLETED",
    "payer":{
        "email_address":"a@yandex.com",
        "payer_id":"WEJUPTK4U53E9",
        "address":{
            "address_line_1":"1 Main St",
            "admin_area_2":"San Jose",
            "admin_area_1":"CA",
            "postal_code":"95131",
            "country_code":"US"
        },
        "name":{
            "given_name":"a",
            "surname":"som"
        },
        "phone":{
            "phone_number":{
                "national_number":"408-214-8270"
            }
        }
    },
    "purchase_units":[{
        "reference_id":"default",
        "amount":{
            "value":"1.01",
            "currency_code":"USD"
        },
        "payee":{
            "email_address":"gr-facilitator@yandex.com",
            "merchant_id":"MSOIGVMKKWAMA"
        },
        "shipping":{
            "name":{
                "full_name":"Mr T"
            },
            "address":{
                "address_line_1":"1234 Main St.",
                "address_line_2":"Unit 1",
                "admin_area_2":"Chicago",
                "admin_area_1":"IL",
                "postal_code":"60652","country_code":"US"
            }
        },
        "payments":{
            "captures":[{
                "status":"COMPLETED",
                "id":"0TA12948FV40723B",
                "final_capture":true,
                "create_time":"2019-02-20T05:06:52Z",
                "update_time":"2019-02-20T05:06:52Z",
                "amount":{
                    "value":"1.01","currency_code":"USD"
                },
            "seller_protection":{
                "status":"ELIGIBLE",
                "dispute_categories":[
                    "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                    "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
                ]}
            }
        ]}
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *purchase_units* and *captures* are arrays:

```
details.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

captures key have objects in side an array. so you can't simply fetch like

```
details.purchase_units.payments[0].captures.id
```

you have to give the position of the captures or loop the array only you can do parsing

```
details.purchase_units.payments[0].captures[0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your json as object using the chrome console you will be able to do what I did in in the image below. purchase_unit is an array so you need to access it using the index.

[image: javascript console]

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to capture all the IDs in an array, you can use wild card:

```
details.purchase_units[*].payments.captures[*].id
```

This will parse complete payload for specified path and collect all the IDs in an array.